# Netbeans interfaces design change automatically

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, interface, splash-screen

Without a splash screen
[image]

Splash Screen source code
[image]

After setting a splash screen
[image]

I am developing a system from Java NetBeans and after developing the whole system I set a splash screen for that. It works properly but it changes my other interface design including font style, color and all. Am excited and I can't imagine what's wrong. But if I delete the splash screen then the interfaces design look at which I created. Please, someone, help me! Thank you!

Comment: Add your relevant code.  Try with Java 8 if using 9+

Comment: Looks like something is changing the Look & Feel. I assume this SplashScreen is not the built-in Java one (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) - correct?